# Have the re-install Homebrew and software from Homebrew each time I close and restart the terminal

Tags: kubernetes, homebrew, devops, kubectl, kustomize

I'm very new to devops and currently working with Homebrew and Kubernetes. The problem I'm facing is that I have to install software like `kubectl` or `kustomize` each time I close and restart the terminal (I'm using Ubuntu terminal on Windows 10).

If I don't reinstall Homebrew etc I get the error message that the specific command (`brew`, `kubectl`, etc.) are not found. When I install it again, it works but I get the message

> kustomize 3.8.4 is already installed and up-to-date. To reinstall 3.8.4, run "brew reinstall kustomize".

So it's actually installed but without running `brew install kustomize`, the command doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks :)